# SSH not landing default user directory

Tags: raspbian, ssh, linux

I have recently installed Raspbian onto a Raspberry Pi. As part of the installation process I changed the user name and group from the default (pi) to my own (let's call it user) using `usermod` and `groupmod`. I as well moved the home directory `/home/pi` to the new user name `/home/user` using `usermod`. Everything works fine except that when I login using SSH instead of landing the new user directory `/home/user` I end up at the home directory `/home`.

Just as the directory `/home/user` exists with permissions 755. In addition to that the `/etc/passwd` file contains an entry that looks like the following:

> user:x:1000:1000:User:/home/user:/bin/bash.

To me everything looks fine, but still when I login from SSH I get a prompt that looks like:

> user@raspberrypi /home $.

Any idea why this may be happening or any simple solution? It's not a big deal but it is confusing me.

Comment: Take a look at your user entry in the /etc/passwd file. Make sure that the entry matches your expected home directory.

Comment: Can you tell us the output of the command `echo $HOME`. That's where the shell believes your user directory is.

Comment: Is it only ssh or any login (if you have another way to log in). Have you restarted the device since the change?

Answer (score 2):

Is the `/home/user` directory owned by user? If you created it as `root` or as `pi` then it probably won't be. Try `sudo chown user /home/user` to remedy this.